# "Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component" when I am deleting from array but working fine with updation of array

Tags: reactjs

I am having a `ExperienceGrid` which renders a list of `ExperienceSingle`.

```
class ExperienceGrid extends React.Component {

  state = {
    experiences: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    //call the API and insert the values to state.experiences
    fetchUserJobExperiencesApi(this.props.api)
      .then(resp => {
        this.setState({
          requestCompleted: true,
          experiences: resp.data._embedded.userJobs
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {} )

  }

  updateExperiencesState_delete = experience => {
      const newExp = pull(this.state.experiences, experience); //pull from Lodash
      this.setState({
        experiences: newExp
      });
    };

    updateExperiencesState_add = experience => {
      this.setState(prevState => {
        return { experiences: prevState.experiences.concat(experience) };
      });
    };

  render(){

    const { experiences} = this.state;

    return(
      <>
      ////other JSX code
      <ul> {
          experiences.map(experience => (
            <li key={experience.userJobId}>
              <ExperienceSingle 
                experience={experience} 
                updateExperiencesState_delete={this.updateExperiencesState_delete}
              />
          </li>
        ))
      }</ul>

    </>
    )

  }

}
```

`ExperienceSingle` has a button for deleting that experience. That button calls the deleting API and on success, it calls `updateExperiencesState_delete`.

```
export default class ExperienceSingle extends Component {

  handleDeletion = () => {
      const { experience, updateExperiencesState_delete } = this.props;
      axios({
        method: "DELETE",
        baseURL: experience._links.self.href
      })
        .then(respose => {
          updateExperiencesState_delete(experience); //remove from ExperienceGrid state
          //update some state of this component
        })
        .catch(error => { //update some state of this component  });
    };

    render(){
      return(
        <>
        ////other Code
        <Confirm
          onCancel={this.closeModal}
          onConfirm={this.handleDeletion}
        />
        </>
      )
    }

}
```

The moment `updateExperiencesState_delete` is called, the **list gets reduced by that element**, but I also see a warning in the console

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.
>       in ExperienceSingle (at ExperienceGrid.js:105)
>       in li (at ExperienceGrid.js:104) index.js:1446
>       React 6
>       handleDeletion ExperienceSingle.js:99

The `updateExperiencesState_add` is called from `NewExperience` and that is working fine. List deleting is the problem.

As per my guess, the unmounted component(in warning) is the one which got deleted. Right?

Any thoughts, please. What am I doing wrong here and what's the right way?

Comment: move api call to `updateExperiencesState_delete`

Comment: @xadm How would that make a difference? Also I can't move the api call because in the promise resolve / error, I need to update State of `ExperienceSingle`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>     .then(respose => {
>       updateExperiencesState_delete(experience); //remove from ExperienceGrid state
>       //update some state of this component
>     })
> ```

`updateExperiencesState_delete(experience)` call will result with removing this item (on parent `setState`)

`// update some state` - `this.setState()` will be called but due to async `setState` nature changes are delayed to next render (in short - see lifecycles).

**Unmounting will occure first - then react by trying to update state of unmounted component fails**, that's the reason of error.

**No `setState` on delete - it doesn't make sense.**

You can freely move api call to parent, error state prop can be passed on fail (if displaying error for single item makes sense, usually this is a top level notification).

Item (on the list) should not handle deleting of itself.

Comment: >No setState on delete - it doesn't make sense ->Thanks for this advice.  >Item (on the list) should not handle deleting of itself. -> Yes, it makes sence.

Comment: And what about **edit** experience? It should be a responsibilty of parent component or the component itself?

Comment: By removing operations to CONTAINER you can simplify item (presentational/view component) to functional, stateless components - it doesn't mean it can't contain another container (deeper relation data). Usually `containers` and (view) `components` are managed in separated folders - different role.